# How can I reprogram this in such a way that, that I don't need to use any sort of variable?

Tags: c, variables, switch-statement, function-definition

This my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int processChoice()
{
    int choice = -1; //I need to execute this code without using any variable
    printf("\nMake a Choice (1, 2, 3 or 0): ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    printf("%d",choice);
    
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 0:
        printf("\nExiting...\n");
        break;
        case 1:
        printf("\nDrawing rectangle...\n");
        break;
        case 2:
        printf("\nDrawing Right triangle...\n");
        break;
        case 3:
        printf("\nDrawing isosceles triangle...\n");
        break;
        
        default:
        printf("\n** Invalid Choice! **\n");
        choice = -1;
    }
    return choice;
}

void showMenu()
{
    printf("\nMenu:");
    printf("\n1. Draw Rectangle");
    printf("\n2. Draw Right triangle");
    printf("\n3. Draw isosceles triangle");
    printf("\n0. Exit program\n");
}


int main()
{
    int x = -1;
    do
    {
        showMenu();
      
    }while(processChoice() != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

That's my code here I used a variable "int Choice = -1;" I'm supposed to execute the same code without using any variable as per guidelines of my mentor.

I'm expecting the same code to be executed without using any variable.

Comment: A code without _any_ variables isn't a very fun program at all, it'd just spit out some information. They may have been trying to steer you to using `getch()` in the `switch` statement, but overall I'd disagree with that advice.

Comment: But ***why***? If you want to read input, then you actually need to store that input somewhere, like in a variable. What is your actual assignment or exercise? Why do your "mentor" say you have to use it without variables? What is the problem that's supposed to solve? Can you please ask your "mentor" for clarifications?

Comment: For this code, you _must_ use a "variable". Perhaps you mean _without_ an _initializer_. That is, change `int Choice = -1;` into `int Choice;`?

Comment: As a possible ***guess***, perhaps the mentor want you to read the input somewhere else (perhaps in its own function), and then pass it as an argument to the `processChoice` function? That still won't be without variables, as the argument is a variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. This is **not a discussion forum** nor a tutoring service, and we cannot read your mentor's mind. If you do not understand what your mentor had in mind, **ask your mentor**. If you don't think the assignment makes sense, **explain why to your mentor**.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14Tt5xnldHCLXpxTi2SqFEB9Ow-dsjO6t?usp=share_link These are the files. Including assignment and remarks over my code.

Comment: Their comment was to remove the `int x` variable in your `#main`, not to remove all variables in your code. You already fixed it mostly, you can just delete `int x = -1;` now.

Comment: There is nothing in your assignment `.pdf` that says "don't use a variable". It only describes the expected behavior of your program with sample inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your mentor means that this declaration in main

```
int x = -1;
```

is not used and should be removed.

As for the function `processChoice` then in any case you need to enter a value from the user. I see the only possibility to write the function without using a variable the following way with using function `getchar`

```
int processChoice( void )
{
    printf("\nMake a Choice (1, 2, 3 or 0): ");
    
    switch( getchar() )
    {
        case '0':
        printf("\nExiting...\n");
        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
        return 0;

        case '1':
        printf("\nDrawing rectangle...\n");
        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
        return 1;

        case '2':
        printf("\nDrawing Right triangle...\n");
        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
        return 2;

        case '3':
        printf("\nDrawing isosceles triangle...\n");
        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
        return 3;
        
        default:
        printf("\n** Invalid Choice! **\n");
        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14Tt5xnldHCLXpxTi2SqFEB9Ow-dsjO6t?usp=share_link Refer here for more details

Comment: I believe Vlad already did, since they saw/commented on the same thing I did when looking.

Comment: @Rogue I did not look the link.

Comment: Take it as an affirmation that your suspicion around `int x` was correct, then.

Comment: @Rogue In any case it is funny.:)